# CiviReport - Localize "Constituent Detail" group header

Tags: civireport, localisation

I'm localizing (Italian) the reports.
As in the object, the "Constituent Detail" group header (the ones with the blue background: RELATIONSHIP, CONTRIBUTION, PARTICIPANT, ..) are not sensible to translation.
I mean, that the translation in the .po file is present but the titles continue to came out in English.
I had also a look in the database and in the code, but with no result.

Can someone help me?

Thanks